# Not correct template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-specialization

Please tell me i have `class Foo`, where i overload `operator<<`.

I need the so that `operator<<` work with `unsigned` type differently.
For this I am trying to declare a template specialization, but wrongly.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::ostream& out)
    : _out(out) {}
    
    template <typename T>
    Foo& operator<<(const T& s) {
        _out << "[]: " << s;
        return *this;
    }
    
    template <>
    Foo& operator<<(const unsigned& s) {
        _out << s;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::ostream& _out;
};


int main() {
    Foo foo(std::cout);
    unsigned a = 5;
    foo << "test\n"; // template 
    foo << a;        // unsigned
}
```

How can you do this correctly?

Comment: Please be more specific than "wrongly". What's wrong with the declaration? (The literal `5` denotes an `int` and is signed.)

Comment: Don't use a template specialization. Just make an overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @super pointed out correctly an overload makes more sense in this case. Just for completeness this is the way template specialization would be done:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(std::ostream& out) : _out(out) {}

  template <typename T>
  Foo& operator<<(const T& s) {
    _out << "[]: " << s;
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  std::ostream& _out;
};

template <>
Foo& Foo::operator<<(const unsigned& s) {
  _out << "[const uint&]: " << s;
  return *this;
}

int main() {
  Foo foo(std::cout);
  unsigned a = 5;
  foo << "test\n";  // template
  foo << a;         // specialized
}
```